# how to compare nextline with readLine() in java?

Tags: java

I am new in java

i have a r.txt file like this

```
A
B
C

X
Y
Z
```

I want to know how to use readline() with "\n", so that when it starts printing it should stop at nextline as blank. As it is giving me an error. I have written like this:

```
while((recordData = br.readLine()) != '\n') //(at line 18 in below code)
```

"error: incompatible operand types  string and char". But with null it does not.

Comment: you are getting `"error: incompatible operand types string and char"` because br.readLine() is a string and you are comparing it to a char '\n' denoted by the single quotes. Use `br.readLine().equals("\n")` double quotes when using strings. However this will probably still not work because of Jigar Joshi's answer

Comment: with `readLine().equals("\n")` you might run into a NPE

Answer (score 3):

[it never returns termination character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

> **Returns:**  A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Answer (score 3):

'\n' is a character and recordData is a String.  You are more interested in the following answer

```
recordData = br.readLine();
while(recordData != null && !recordData.trim().isEmpty()) {
  System.out.print(recordData);
  recordData = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is input, the `readLine()` method will return a single line of text, without the line termination character(s), so there will be no `'\n'` character read.

For the empty line in the `r.txt` file you will get an empty or blank string, so instead of line 18, you can just write

```
while (((recordData = br.readLine()) != null) && !recordData.trim().isEmpty()))
```

The `trim()` method will cover cases where the blank line is not just a new line, but contains "white space" characters (e.g., SPACE and TAB).

On another note, the `recordData` declaration is not needed at all. You can just reuse the `line` variable.